# How to set up a project using webpack and babel?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Does anyone have any simple guides for setting up a react project using babel and webpack with clear explanations of the instructions inside package.json?

Answer (score 2):

you might be interested on this link in the docs.
https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html which points to this post for creating from scratch
https://blog.usejournal.com/creating-a-react-app-from-scratch-f3c693b84658

Comment: Life saver, thank you